# Cannot connect to x11vnc server from other client

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, x11

Hello guys I have installed x11vnc server on MAC OS el capital but trying to connect remotely and stream the images of desktop only a black image is rendered to vnc client do you have any idea? I am using it as below
x11vnc -forever -shared -many -display :0

Comment: macos does not run X11 you need a normal vnc to run on the Mac

Comment: the documentation of x11vnc states that it can run on macos furtherlly x11vnc is official on the brew repository I have installed via brew install x11vnc

Answer (score 2):

x11vnc is a server for X displays - i.e. you can only connect to the X display running on your Mac - not the ordinary Mac desktop. This means that if you're running for example an X desktop in a window with emacs, xeyes, or whatever odd program - you can connect to that.

You cannot connect to a desktop running Finder, Safari, and similar. Those are not X programs and are not displayed on an X display. In order to connect to them, you'll need a macOS native VNC server. Such a server is bundled with macOS. You'll need to open System Preferences, then Sharing and then enable Screen Sharing.

Comment: There is no option either by using XQuartz? Or XQuartz is a way to have x11 libraries to mac os?

Comment: You seem to be confused. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve? That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: XQuartz is an X display server. It makes it possible to have an X display on your Mac, where you can display X programs such as xclock, xeyes, xterm, or whatever you like. It isn't an X11 library, nor does it have anything to do with VNC as such. It doesn't have anything at all to do with ordinary macOS programs such as Finder, Safari, iTunes, or similar - they're not displayed through XQuartz.